# WooCommerce shipping price INCLUSIVE tax

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce I can only enter the shipping price excluding tax.
How can I make the given price including tax?

The settings to show 'prices including tax' only applies to the products.

So for example if I enter in the settings shipping €1,00
It shows on the checkout €1,21 (0,21 = tax)

It should be €1,00 (incl. 0,21 tax)
(Don't care about the calculation here, it's just an example)

Thanks if anybody has a solution or function for this.

Comment: Got the same problem, I'd just input the shipping cost excl. tax.

Comment: Just need to uncheck Shipping shown in the page in Aibrean's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31345391/1788684

Comment: I'd say this is a bug in WooCommerce.  Though if they fix it, the fix would need to be behind a checkbox to enable the fix, otherwise it would break existing websites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A year after the original question I just hit the same problem and there is not a lot out there to help.

On investigation this turns out to be a problem with the shipping tax calculation from "class-wc-tax.php" which as you can see below hard codes shipping to be tax exclusive.

```
     /**
     * Calculate the shipping tax using a passed array of rates.
     *
     * @param   float       Price
     * @param   array       Taxation Rate
     * @return  array
     */
    public static function calc_shipping_tax( $price, $rates ) {
        $taxes = self::calc_exclusive_tax( $price, $rates );
        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_calc_shipping_tax', $taxes, $price, $rates );
    }
```

It turns out that for some reason that woo have pushed this assumption of shipping being tax exclusive through their down stream tax calculations so you will need to add a couple of filters to your functions.php in order to fix things.

1) The first to calculate the inclusive tax

```
 function yourname_fix_shipping_tax( $taxes, $price, $rates) {

        if(wc_prices_include_tax()){
            return  WC_Tax::calc_inclusive_tax( $price, $rates );
        }

        return $taxes;
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_calc_shipping_tax', 'yourname_fix_shipping_tax',10,3);
```

Careful that you don't forget the 10,3 at the end of add_filter. The 10 is the priority which I have left at the default. The 3 is the number of arguments. You really need this one - the filter displays behavioral problems if you leave it out.

2) The second filter is to fix the totals in downstream calculations.

```
function yourname_fix_totals( $cart) {

    if(wc_prices_include_tax()){        
        $cart->shipping_total -= $cart->shipping_tax_total;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'yourname_fix_totals');
```

---

### Detail for those that worry that this is real money and real taxes we are talking about

The first filter is fairly straight forward - it simply recalculates the tax in the inclusive case.

The second filter is to deal with woo pushing the assumption of exclusive tax further into their tax calculations.

Around line 1396 of 'class-wc-cart.php' we have the following.

```
// Grand Total - Discounted product prices, discounted tax, shipping cost + tax
    $this->total = max( 0, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', round( $this->cart_contents_total + $this->tax_total + $this->shipping_tax_total + $this->shipping_total + $this->fee_total, $this->dp ), $this ) );
```

What this wants to do is add the shipping tax to the shipping total which we don't want it to do - and they have hard coded it in......

What we will do is use the conveniently located 'woocommerce_calculate_totals' filter() a few lines above around line 1392 to subtract the shipping tax from the total before it all gets added up using the second filter above.

```
// Allow plugins to hook and alter totals before final total is calculated
do_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', $this );
```

In an earlier cut of this post from a few weeks back I was worried that this would be a can of worms - and it is turning out to be just that now that I can test things.

So **huge** caveat here. Test your final tax totals and subtotals thoroughly - this is no longer possibly a risk. Woo *have* made the assumption of tax exclusive shipping and *have* pushed it through their downstream calculations. Unfortunately you will *have* to pay tax to your respective governments even if  there was a bug in you code.

Remember also when testing that when you change from exclusive to inclusive taxes in woocommerce settings that old prices are not affected, so you may need to use clean test data.

With all that said so far it is looking ok for me, but in my scenario I am bypassing large amounts of woo - I am not using any of their front end code which means I may not have found other places impacted by the assumption of tax exclusive shipping.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your post. 
I have this problem and tried your solution.
However, I couldn't make it work.
"woocommerce_calc_shipping_tax" filter is just not applied as "calc_shipping_tax" is often  not called - I couldn't understand why and when. The break point in debugger even is not hit when I refresh cart or checkout page.
"woocommerce_calc_shipping_tax" result is always being modified by some further filters, no matter how high priority I assign. Moreover, it looks like it's result , a shipping cost deducted by shipping tax , has tax added, calculated on this, decreased value.

Comment: Same problem. This code doesn't work for me :( I am having the problem of setting a maximum shipping rate and because of shipping tax rounding, it messes up the maximum rate calculation meaning that the total shipping cost goes above the maximum amount due to the rounding. I can't work out how to get it to function either. For tax purposes, it's essential that tax also be calculated on shipping (so unticking 'Shipping tax' is not an option.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative solution is to manually adjust the pricing for shipping so it becomes VAT exclusive. I.e. if shipping incl 20% tax is 6 EUR, adjust it to 5 EUR. Note that this only works if your tax rate is the same for all shipping destinations.

Comment: This isn't a correct answer. This doesn't allow you to get a specific price due to WooCommerce rounding.

Comment: I think in the vast majority of cases this is the most sensible answer, I've not encountered any rounding issues thus far.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned WooCommerce devs have hardcoded the calculation of shipping tax to be exclusive of tax. To change this, first adjust the shipping tax by using the `woocommerce_calc_shipping_tax`:

```php
function calculateShippingInclusiveOfTax($taxes, $shippingPrice, $taxRates)
{
    // If site-wide configuration is inclusive of taxes calculate taxes as such
    if (wc_prices_include_tax()) {
        return  WC_Tax::calc_inclusive_tax($shippingPrice, $taxRates);
    }

    // Reaching this point means side-wide configuration is exclusive of tax, therefore return shipping taxes
    // as such
    return $taxes;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_calc_shipping_tax', 'calculateShippingInclusiveOfTax', 10, 3);
```

After doing this, the Shipping Taxes will display correctly on the Cart. However, WooCommerce internally uses `Shipping cost without Tax + Calculated Tax (either from inclusive price or exclusive price)` to come up with the Shipping Tax Total, and up until now, we haven't changed the Shipping cost without Tax value anywhere. Because of this, our total will still be incorrect. So we have to either change the "Shipping cost without Tax" value or just remove the Total Shipping Tax from the Cart Total once everything has been summed. As you can see, the latter is easier, so we do that by using the `woocomerce_calculated_total` hook:

```php
function fixCartTotalAmountCalculationDueToMakingShippingInclusiveOfTax($total, $cart)
{
    if (wc_prices_include_tax()) {
        $total -= $cart->shipping_tax_total;
    }

    return $total;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_calculated_total', 'fixCartTotalAmountCalculationDueToMakingShippingInclusiveOfTax', 10, 2);
```

Refer to line 865 of `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php` for more information.

#### Bonus: Insight on why the answer by [Brenton Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44604262/3076513) does not work:

First, the `woocommerce_calculate_totals` hook is an action instead of a filter. Modifying values is not the intended use of an action, a filter should be used instead.

Putting that aside, the error is that the Cart Totals have already been calculated at the point where the action is executed based on the sum `Shipping cost without Tax + Calculated Tax`, so the correct operation would be `$cart->total - $cart->shipping_tax_total`.