# Maximum shipping cost / woocommerce/

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

first, sorry for my english.

I have shipping class called Big Materials, when is 10€ fix plus 2€ per item. I´ve set the maximum shipping cost on 24€ with this code.

When I put 8 pcs to cart, the shipping cost is 26€. When I put 9 pcs to cart, the shipping cost is 28€, when I put 10 pcs to cart, the shipping cost is 24€ which I set.

I don´t know, where is the problem.

Is in the tax or … ?

Can you help me?

Thanks.

```
/**
 * Function to set a minimum/cap on the shipping rates.
 */
function my_minimum_limit_shipping_rates_function( $rates, $package ) {
    $methods = WC()->shipping()->get_shipping_methods();
    $shipping_limit = 24; // The maximum amount would be $24
    // Loop through all rates
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        // Check if the rate is higher then a certain amount
        if ( $rate->cost > $shipping_limit ) {
            $rate->cost = $shipping_limit;
            // Recalculate shipping taxes
            if ( $method = $methods[ $rate->get_method_id() ] ) {
                $taxes = WC_Tax::calc_shipping_tax( $rate->cost, WC_Tax::get_shipping_tax_rates() );
                $rate->set_taxes( $method->is_taxable() ? $taxes : array() );
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'my_minimum_limit_shipping_rates_function', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `$rate->cost` to `$rates[$rate_id]` and check

```
/**
 * Function to set a minimum/cap on the shipping rates.
 */
function my_minimum_limit_shipping_rates_function( $rates, $package ) {
    $methods = WC()->shipping()->get_shipping_methods();
    $shipping_limit = 24; // The maximum amount would be $24
    // Loop through all rates
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        // Check if the rate is higher then a certain amount
        if ( $rate->cost > $shipping_limit ) {
            $rates[$rate_id]->cost = $shipping_limit;                
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'my_minimum_limit_shipping_rates_function', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Hi Alice, thx for the your advice. But still the same. Shipping cost is going up to 28,8€ and after passing this limit is going back to 24€. I think that is there something about tax calculation. We have 20% tax. So 24€ plus 20% tax is 28,8€. I don´t know nothing about code, but i think, that is a way to set shipping calculation without taxes.

Comment: I have the same problem although the code I am using is simpler than yours (I'll post below for reference). I do believe you are right that it is annoyingly due to tax calculation rounding. :( I'm still looking for a solution. I'll post here if I find one.

Comment: I just realised the code I have is pretty much exactly the same lol. Again, I'll post a solution to the tax rounding if I find one. Although it would be really nice if Automattic could actually calculate the shipping tax correctly to start with :/

Comment: I found this about shipping tax but unfortunately, the code does not work for me and I have no idea how to make it work. Someone else may have some input. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44604262/5204226

Comment: I've opened an issue on Woocommerce github. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/23710 Feel free to weigh in. In the mean time, I have had to disable tax on shipping (not legal in my country), but the only way to accurately calculate shipping :/

Comment: Sorry for all the comments. FYI, both versions of the code above causes tax to not be calculated on shipping and included in the total price. With this code active, tax is only calculated on the product total :(

Comment: Hi Rose :) it seems, that isn´t easy to find simple solution. I didn´t find it yet. Please, If you will, place it here. BTW if it´s an easiest way to set a maximum shipping cost without a problem with taxes, anyone feel free to place it here. Thank you all!

Comment: Sorry as I am late,
 if you don't need taxes on shipping, simply delete // Recalculate shipping taxes - section 
I mean the whole if block.....I am updating the code too

Comment: Unfortunately @Branislav, it seems like Woocommerce doesn't want to have a bar of fixing this ongoing issue with their calculations. I was told just to enter the shipping rate as tax exclusive, which as we know, causes issues in scenarios like this. At this point, I have had to give up and use the Table Rate Shipping plugin as it's the only thing I can find that has the option to enter in shipping tax inclusive and set a max rate. I just don't have the time to find how to make this work for what should be a simple solution :(

Comment: thx Alice for your help. Unfortunately yours change of my code (delete whole block with taxes) doesn´t solved the problem. Even the shipping can be higher than 30€ in this case.

Comment: When i´ve set shipping not taxable, the code works great. The shipping cost is not higher than 24€. The problem is, that i need shipping taxable because of our state laws etc.

Comment: after appliying tax ? can the tax be more than 24 ? or it should not cross 24 at any situation ?

Comment: 24€ is the limit with the taxes. (tax is 4€ here). The problem is, that this code make my taxable 24€ taxable again. in final it is 28.8€. On my website the shipping cost can´t be higher than 24€. But i have shipping class called big materials, when i´ve set shipping cost 10€ fix and 2€ per piece. When the customer buys 9pcs of big materials, the shipping cost in the cart is 28€, when he  buys 10 pcs, the shipping cost is 24€...thats the problem. my site is https://vigia.sk/ you can try it. Find product called OSB and put it in to the cart 9pcs and then 10 pcs. you will see...thank you Alice!

Comment: anyone who can help please?